# BigQuery: Add ingestion timestamp to records ingested via streaming insert

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm streaming records into BigQuery.  I need to record when each row actually makes its way into BigQuery.  How can I do this?  I don't mind if this is off by up to three seconds.

Comment: Would you mind adding a column to your table, which specifies the timestamp of ingest?

Comment: @khan that's exactly what I have in mind.  The new column should indicate when a record became available for querying in BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Bigquery doesn't offer this functionality.

You need to script it so when it arrives in BQ it already has the column with the correct timestamp value zst5.

Comment: Too bad.  BigQuery adds a unpredictable amount of ingestion latency, so unfortunately I can't add this value myself.

Comment: what kind of ingestion latency are you talking about?

Comment: I mean latency that occurs during bigquery's streaming inserts.  Specifically, the amount of time between when bigquery acknowledges it receives a row and when that row will show up in queries.  The BigQuery doc entitled 'Streaming Data Into BigQuery' says 'Streamed data is available for real-time analysis within a few seconds of the first streaming insertion into a table'.  The timestamp I want is the moment at which the data becomes available for analysis.